# Finding elements of std::vector in std::set

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, set

I have two containers `std::set` and `std::vector` and my task is to return elements from `std::vector` which are present in `std::set`. What is the most effective way to achieve it? 
Simple solution:
Iterate through elements of vector and call `set.find` on each and then `vector.erase` if not found.

Comment: Is the vector sorted or unsorted?

Comment: Sounds like you might want something like [`std::set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) (but it requires the vector to be sorted).

Comment: Sorry for inconsistency. For the time being (and it may remain unchanged) vector is unsorted and small. Set has much more elements, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use more STL :)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    std::set<int> s {1, 3, 5};

    v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                          [&s](int a) { return s.find(a) == s.end(); }),
            v.end());

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: Since I want to keep elements in vector that are present in set, the solution needs  a small correction `return s.find(a) == s.end()`;

Answer (score 2):

How about just looking for every element? If your vector is not sorted, then there's no way around `n log(n)`

```
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> result;
for(auto&& el: myvector) {
    auto it_found = myset.find(el);
    if(it != myset.end())
        result.push_back(*it_found);
}
```

Now `result` has all the elements that are in both.

PS: Haven't compiled the code, there might be slight errors.

Comment: Not 100% sure but isn't this O(n^2)?  Don't you need to iterate the vector and then use the `find` member function of the set to get O(n log n)?

Comment: @NathanOliver Actually I'm not sure. It might be `n^2`. I'm at a loss a little because `std::set` is sorted.

Comment: But you're not searching the set.  `for(auto&& el: myset)` iterates the the sets so that is `n` and then `std::find(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), el);` searches the vector which is another `n` so that is `O(n^2)` right?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, you're right. I guess it's `n^2`.

Comment: I believe if you flip it around you'll get `O(n log n)`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Durp.  Yeah, they don't have to be equal.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'll flip them. Good idea.

Comment: My current implementation is what you mentioned:        auto iter = myVec.begin();
  while (iter != myVec.end()) 
  {
      if (mySet.find(*iter) == mySet.end())
      {
        myVec.erase(iter);
      }
      ++iter;
  }

Comment: @rublow That's the best you can get for a not-sorted vector.

Comment: @rublow `vector::erase` invalidates iterators. But you can use the fact that it returns an iterator to the next element: `if (mySet.find(*iter) == mySet.end()) { iter = myVec.erase(iter); } else { ++iter; }`. Also it will be slightly more efficient to traverse the vector in reverse so it isn't shifting around elements that need to be removed during the erase.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way is probably to use `std::set_intersection`. But you should sort a vector to make it work:

```
int main()
{
    std::set<int>    s{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    std::vector<int> v{7,5,10,9};
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end()); // should not bother you if vector is small

    std::vector<int> intersection;
    std::set_intersection(s.begin(), s.end(), v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(intersection));

    for(int n : intersection)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
}
```

Prints: `5 7`

Comment: If `n` is the size of the vector and `m` is the size of the set, this is `O(n*lg(n) + n + m)`. It can be done in `O(n*lg(m))`. (And set iteration is slow.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on relative size of set and vector, remove_if may be the right thing...

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::set<int>    s{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    std::vector<int> v{7,5,10,9};

    v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](int e){return s.count(e) == 0;}), v.end());


    for(int n : v)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look for the most *cpu*-effective way of doing this in terms of *complexity*, have additional memory and a good hash function, you can do it in O(n + m):

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::set<int> s;
std::unordered_set<int> us{s.cbegin(), s.cend(), s.size()};

v.erase(
    std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
        [&us] (const int entry) { return us.find(entry) == us.cend(); }),
    v.end());
```

Explanation: you iterate over your `set` once (O(m)) to prepare `unordered_set`. Then you iterate through your `vector` once (O(n)), performing `unordered_set::find` (0(1)) each step. It gives you the resulting complexity of O(n+m).

Also, the size of `unordered_set` being equal to the size of `set` and a good hash function helps to reduce constant part in complexity of `std::unordered_set::find`.

See [***live example***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69717385727c0b17).

Bear in mind, however, that lower complexity doesn't necessarily mean faster execution in particular circumstances (for example, because of extra allocations).

Comment: Thank you, for your explanation. However (as you mentioned) I'd like to erase elements 'on fly' without additional memory use.

Comment: In this case you can replace `set` with `unordered_set` if you don't care about ordering properties of `set` or use [boost::multi_index_container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html) with `ordered_unique` index type for utilising `set`-like properties and `hashed_unique` for filtering out unneeded entries with O(n) complexity.